# Java Command Line Trouble with Reading a Class from a Jar Archive

Tags: java, command-line

I am trying to run a java based tool using a command line syntax as the following: java -cp archive.jar archiveFolder.theMainClassName.Although the class I am searching for, a main class, "theMainClassName" is in the archive.jar and in the archiveFolder given at input, I keep getting the error that my class is not seen. Does anybody have any ideas concerning this problem? Thank you in advance

Comment: Run the command `jar tf <your.jar>` and post the result.

Cut and paste the exact command line that you are using, and the exact error message output by the java command.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a concrete example of what *does* work, so you can compare your own situation.

Take this code and put it anywhere, in a file called `MainClass.java`. (I've assumed a directory called `src` later. Normally you'd arrange the source to match the package, of course.)

```
package archiveFolder;

public class MainClass
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println("I'm MainClass");
    }
}
```

Then run each of these commands:

```
# Compile the source
javac -d . src/MainClass.java

# Build the jar file
jar cf archive.jar archiveFolder

# Remove the unpackaged binary, to prove it's not being used
rm -rf archiveFolder # Or rmdir /s /q archiveFolder on Windows

# Execute the class
java -cp archive.jar achiveFolder.MainClass
```

The result:

```
I'm MainClass
```

How are you building your jar file? Is the code in the appropriate package?

Answer (score 3):

Does theMainClassName class have the following package line at the top:

```
package archiveFolder
```

You need the class file to be in the same directory structure as the declared package. So if you had something like:

```
org/jc/tests/TestClass.class
```

its source file would have to look like this:

```
package org.jc.tests;

public class TestClass {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.printf("This is a test class!\n");
  }
}
```

Then you could use the following to create the jar file and run it from the command line (assuming the current directory is at the top level, just above org):

```
$ jar -cf testJar.jar org/jc/tests/*.class
$ java -cp testJar.jar org.jc.tests.TestClass
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps with `java -jar archive.jar`?

Of course, it supposes the manifest points to the right class...

You should give the exact message you got, it might shed more light.

EDIT:  See [Working with Manifest Files: The Basics](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/deployment/jar/manifestindex.html) for information on setting the application entry point (Main class) in your jar manifest file.

Comment: This doesn't actually answer the question... he's not attempting to run the jar but a specific class in the jar. It's almost certainly a packaging problem.

Comment: I agree that this doesn't answer the specific question asked, but other people searching SO might be suffering from a problem with their manifest.  They'll run across this question, so I think it's worth having this answer here.

Answer (score 1):

Usually this happens when a dependent class (static member) is not found - like this, using log4j:

```
public class MyClass {
  private static Logger log = Logger.getLogger("com.example");
}
```

The reason is that the initialization of such a static member can be understood as part of the class loading - errors causing the class not to be available (loadable), resulting in the error you described.

Static constructors are another possible reason:

```
public class MyClass {
  static {
     // <b>any</b> error caused here will cause the class to 
     // not be loaded. Demonstrating with stupid typecast.
     Object o = new String();
     Integer i = (Integer) o;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think others have covered some common stuff here.  I'd jar tf the jar and make sure the class is listed.  I'd also double-check that the class is public and the method is "public static void main(String[] arg)".